# How can I detect a meeting room in list of users returned from the Microsoft Graph?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I need to return a list of users from the Microsoft Graph. I am doing this via the /v1.0/users endpoint.

e.g.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
```

However, it currently returns accounts for Meeting Rooms set up as resources in Exchange.

I can't see a simple way to detect these and thus filter them from my list easily.

Does anyone know what I could filter by, or look for in the object that would point to it being a resource vs. a user account?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this solution ?

Comment: Sadly no.  Any alternative suggestions would be welcome and accepted as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been running into this issue as well for awhile now. However, I just stumbled upon this update that looks like the new People API endpoint in the Graph API can support distinguishing between users and rooms/resources: https://dev.office.com/blogs/people-api-available-in-microsoft-graph-v1

I just ran a quick test in the sandbox that confirms that this query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$filter=personType/subclass eq 'Room'
```

returns a list of my tenant's room resources. It also, nicely, seems that the `User.ReadBasic.All` permission is sufficient for the `/me/people` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Microsoft Graph is not able to distinguish whether the mailbox is a user or a room. As a workaround, we can get the rooms using [GetRoomLists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx) and [GetRooms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532566(v=exchg.80).aspx) of EWS. Here is an example getting room lists and rooms for your reference:

```
// Return all the room lists in the organization.
// This method call results in a GetRoomLists call to EWS.
EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();

// Display the room lists.
foreach (EmailAddress address in myRoomLists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0} Mailbox Type: {1}", address.Address, address.MailboxType);
}

private static void GetRooms(ExchangeService service)
{
     // Return all the room lists in the organization
     EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();

     // Retrieve the room list that matches your criteria
     EmailAddress myAddress = new EmailAddress("building31@contoso.com");
     foreach (EmailAddress address in myRoomLists)
     {
          if (address == myAddress)
          {
               Console.WriteLine("Found {0} in room list", myAddress);
          }
     }

     // Expand the selected collection to get a list of rooms.
     System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<EmailAddress> myRoomAddresses = service.GetRooms(myAddress);

     // Display the individual rooms.
     foreach (EmailAddress address in myRoomAddresses)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0}", address.Address);
     }
}
```

And if you wnat the Microsoft Graph to support to distinguish the type of mailbox, you can submit the feedback from link [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: thanks but saying we should use another unrelated API is not a solution. this would mean needing to authenticate etc... in a completely different way.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API has been updated : you can use know the GetRooms method Fei Xue was talking about.
It is only a workaround but it should suit your needs : use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms` to retrieve all the meeting rooms in your organization.

Comment: That [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findrooms?view=graph-rest-beta) only limits to the first 100 rooms. We have a client that is a big organization, which have more than 100 rooms. :(

Comment: Is there a odata.nextLink in the response ? If there is [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/graph/paging) for this route you could use data.nextLink value to get the next page.

Comment: Maybe if you have that much rooms, you should first retrieve room [lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findroomlists?view=graph-rest-beta) and then rooms by room list

Comment: nope there's none since getting all rooms just limit to 100. But getting the room based on the room lists is a good idea. But does all rooms be inside a room list? My concern is that some rooms are not in a room list and we may miss that.